# Restrict users to be able to use only single application in Android device

Tags: android

how to Restrict users to be able to use only single application in Android device ?
That is I write an  3rd party application which is launched after start up of Android phone  and users should not be allowed to access other applications in device.
can this be possible in Android?
can any one suggest me the possible ways in achieving this?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629833/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible without modifyieng the the Android system itself.

You can try various things to *simulate* the effect:
 - Implement your app as a home screen intent receiver and set it as default
 - implement browser, email, sharing etc etc intent receivers for your app and set it as default

The only way to make this entirely safe & user-proof is to customize your root-system, means that you would compile android yourself and add various changes (i.e. cut off Home-Button and so on).

Android is more flexible than iPhone but not flexible enough to have it completely secure for user interactions. You're planning for CAR usage, right?

Comment: `and set it as default` You can't do this, only the user can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do but lots of efforts are required for this.
below are the steps how to do:

1. Create group
2. Inside group place user
3. Inside group place application
4. Provide mechanism on device to ask for credentials from users
5. Once user entered their credentials then redirect this user onto specific group(on device) so inside group declared applications only users can access.