# Block an android device

Tags: java, android, blocking

I'm developing an app for Android Tablet PC and I need to allow user to run only exact applications.
1. Is there any way to deny other applications execution?
2. Is it possible to show some block screen with password prompt and deny user to run anything until the authentication will be passed?

Unfortunately I haven't find any info :(

Comment: Almost identical to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629833

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this without a custom build of Android.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking applications (and not just activities within an application) then it would not be "safe" for google to allow you to block other programs from running. If you had your own (non-stock) version of Android that you were deploying on company devices for example, then perhaps you could do that, but if you're just making an app, it would not be wise to have an app prevent other ones from running. You could perhaps set up some kind of shared memory resource with some flags that other apps could look at upon launching to see if they should proceed or not, but that is about it.

Comment: It is standard Android build.

Comment: Then I would highly advise just using a shared memory space to set flags for each app and just check the flags as soon as the app starts and have it shut itself down if the flags say so.

Comment: Could you provide me with some more info regarding your answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a replacement for the launcher & app drawer so that you can manage the application launch process.  There is a demo for creating a launcher in the SDK, and a short thread about it [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/467aa8f77ceadbd5#)